# How to import a Bootstrap Web Application into a Google Web Application in Eclipse

Tags: html, eclipse, google-app-engine, web-applications, import

I have a Google Web Application set up in Eclipse and it is connected to a Google App Engine back-end (using datastore to store information) connected with a Java Servlet.

I also have an existing Bootstrap Web Application that contains HTML, CSS, and javascript files. I was wondering if there is any way to import this existing project into my Google Web App and if so, where do I put these files? This is the layout of my Google Web App in Eclipse..

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRo5x.png]

I know that for a Dynamic web project these files go into "Web Content" but this file does not exist for Google Web Applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The top-level directory of a Java EE web module is considered the document root of the application. The document root is where JSP pages, client-side classes and archives, and static web resources, such as HTML/CSS/JS files, are stored.

Hence put such files into your war directory or any subdirectory (e.g. static).

However, **do not put them into WEB-INF directory**. It is a private area of the web application and all files under WEB-INF directory are not accessible from outside (e.g. browser).